# Fast algorithm for finding a minimum cost path through points in the plane

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Consider the following problem:

There are $n$ points in the plane.
Starting from one of them I want to visit each of them once (except the starting node which has to be visited twice) but in a way that minimizes the cost of the total path.

The weight of each edge changes depending on the path followed.
For example imagine $n=3$: $A$, $B$, $C$ and we start at $A$. 
The weight of the edge $xy$ is $Sd_{xy}$, where $d_{xy}$ is the distance between the points $x$ and $y$ and $S$ is a given constant)
If I pick the edge $A\to B$, the weight of the edge $B\to A$ is now
$(S-s_B)d_{AB}$ because $B$ changes $S$ by a constant amount $s_B$. 
Similarly if I pick the edge $A\to C$, the weight of the edge $B\to C$ is now
$(S-s_C)d_{AC}$ because visiting $C$ changes $S$ by a constant amount $s_C$.

Developing the $n=3$ case, imagine S=11, $d_{AB}=5,d_{AC}=3,d_{BC}=4$ and $s_{A}=2,s_{B}=5,s_{C}=4$.
Then there are 4 possible paths:

A->B->C->A with cost $11*5+(11-5)*4+(11-5-4)*3$

(we stop once we reach A because 11-5-4-2=0)

A->B->A->C with cost $11*5+(11-5)*5+(11-4-2)*3$

A->C->B->A with cost $11*3+(11-4)*4+(11-4-5)*5$

A->C->A->B with cost $11*3+(11-4)*3+(11-4-2)*5$

For $n=4$ there will be 3*3!=18 possible paths and so on.

I know that $s_A+s_B+s_C=S$. This generalizes for $n$ points.
 What is an efficient algorithm for finding the minimum cost path?

Comment: Shouldn't Euclidean TSP reduce to this pretty straightforwardly?

Comment: Please give a more precise definition of the problem. Definition by example ends up being vague, especially when you give two identical examples of everything. Does using edge $xy$ change the weight of every edge in the graph according to the value of $s_y$? Does it change the weight only of the edges that aren't in the path built so far? Or does it only change the weight of the edge $y\to x$, as suggested by your examples? (The last would have no effect, since the edge $y\to x$ can't be used, since $x$ and $y$ have both already been visited.)

Comment: The edit, by a different user, has introduced paths that visit a vertex more than once. Is this supposed to be allowed?

Comment: Yes we have to visit the starting node A twice so that we make S−$\sum_{i}s_{i}=0$. (so yes $\sum_{i}s_{i}=S$).

Comment: @deb "There are n points in the plane. Starting from one of them I want to visit each of them once but in a way that minimizes the cost of the total path." This says nothing about visiting the start node twice. And it certainly doesn't suggest that a path $A\to B\to A\to C$, as introduced in the edit, is allowed.

Comment: fixed the wording about visiting the start node twice. Hopefully the example clarifies which paths are allowed

Comment: @deb Please give a precise definition, instead of attempting to define by example. You're looking for paths that visit the start node twice, even if the second visit is somewhere in the middle? Please clarify the points I raised earlier about exactly which edges change in weight at each step.